# How do assign a value(string) from database to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda

My issue is im trying to write a lambda expression! Problem is that I am not sure I am doing it right.

```
var result = dataset.student.Where(n => n.ID == num);
**num is a value recieved from id text box
```

var result stores my object pulled from database (which is a person), so now i need to assign the textbox "FirstNameTxtBox" with result FirstName

```
this.FirstNameTextBox = result.Where(n=>n.FirstName);
```

this is where I am failing as my expression keeps out "cannot convert String to bool. To be honest not sure if it is the right expression.
Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = result.Select(n => n.FirstName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: its telling me cannot convert string to System Windows Control Textbox what would you suggest to get around?

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch query result using extension First or FirstOrDefault.

Read for more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

```
this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = result.Where(n=>n.FirstName).First();
```

or

```
this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = dataset.student.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == num).FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need lambda. Simple get the first item of your result.

```
this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = result.First().FirstName;
// or
this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = result[0].FirstName;
```

Or to simplify from the beginning

```
this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = dataset.student.First(n => n.ID == num).FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use FirstOrDefault() and check if its not null:

```
var result = dataset.student.Where(n => n.ID == num).FirstOrDefault();
if(result != null)
{
    this.FirstNameTextBox.Text = result.FirstName;
}
```